# having trouble filtering out multiple rows if a specific criteria is met

Tags: php

EDIT: ISSUE RESOLVED THANK YOU!

I'm having trouble figuring out a method to omit BOTH entries (time and message_time) from my echo'd Table in a row, if the value for $row['time']; is returned 0.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup();
include($phpbb_root_path.'config.'.$phpEx);

mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpasswd") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die(mysql_error());

// Get all the data from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phpbb_mchat WHERE user_id = '$userid' ORDER BY     message_time DESC") 
or die(mysql_error());  

echo "<table class='sortable'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Saved On</th> <th>Time (MM:SS)</th> </tr>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
// Print out the contents of each row into a table
if ($row['time'] != "0") {
echo "<tr><td>"; 
echo $row['message_time'] =  date( "F j, Y, g:ia", $row['message_time']);
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['time'];
echo "</td></tr>";  
 }
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: why not just: `if (row['time'] != 0) { ...`

Comment: if if (row['time'] != 0) { wont that just omit time and not the entire row in the table containing (row['time'] and (row['message_time']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to omit rows in the table where "time" is 0

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
  // Print out the contents of each row into a table
  if ($row['time'] != "0") {
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $row['message_time'] =  date( "F j, Y, g:ia", $row['message_time']);
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['time'];
    echo "</td></tr>";  
  }
}
```

The entire row will be omited if $row['time'] is 0

Comment: you're too kind thank you let me give this a shot i'll upvote soon

Comment: I updated my code above maybe I messed up one of the brackets }

Comment: the table doesn't load any results or is omitting all results, but it shouldn't: [table before your code is applied]  Saved On  Time (MM:SS)
June 26, 2014, 4:14pm 00:03
June 26, 2014, 4:14pm 00:01
June 26, 2014, 4:14pm 00:01
June 26, 2014, 4:14pm 00:03
June 26, 2014, 4:14pm 00:03
June 26, 2014, 4:14pm 00:02
June 26, 2014, 4:14pm 00:02
June 26, 2014, 4:14pm 0
June 26, 2014, 4:14pm 00:02
June 26, 2014, 4:14pm 0
June 26, 2014, 4:14pm 00:02
June 26, 2014, 4:14pm 0

Comment: try add quotes to the 0, if ($row['time'] != "0") {...}, "00:01" got converted to 0 during the conversion thus passing it false and omitting the rows